# StrToMember does not accept calculated measure (mdx)

Tags: mdx

I try to create a member by using some calculated measure (I have called it 'MyDay' here). I return date members on an axis and the members have a property which I want to use. I can return the property itself, but cannot create the member and work with it.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[MyDay] as DatePart("d", MyDateDimension.CurrentMember.Properties("MyProperty"))

MEMBER MyDateDimension.[MyMember] AS  
    STRTOMEMBER("MyDateDimension.&[2015]&[4]&[" + CStr([Measures].[MyDay]) + "]")

MEMBER [Measures].[SomeOther] as (MyDateDimension.[MyMember], [Measures].[Other]

SELECT
{ 
    MyDateDimension.Members)

} ON COLUMNS,

{
    [Measures].[MyDay] //works,
    [Measures].[SomeOther] //error
}
```

If I replace 'MyDateDimension.CurrentMember' by some hard coded date member,
it works fine.
And this also works:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[SomeOther] as (STRTOMEMBER("MyDateDimension.&[2015]&[4]&[" + CStr([Measures].[MyDay]) + "]"), [Measures].[Other])
```

Comment: You are missing some part of query..Also I can see you don't have a `WHERE` clause..Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the strToMember directly in the SomeMeasure then things start to function:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MyDay] AS 
    Datepart
    ("d"
     ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
    ) 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[MyMember] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      '[Date].[Calendar].&[200603' + Cstr([Measures].[MyDay]) + ']'
     ,constrained
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[SomeOther] AS 
    (
      //[Date].[Calendar].[MyMember]
      StrToMember
      (
        '[Date].[Calendar].&[200603' + Cstr([Measures].[MyDay]) + ']'
       ,constrained
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[MyDay]
   ,[Measures].[SomeOther]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Tail
  (
    Descendants
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[8]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
    )
   ,10
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

A slightly tidier version:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MyDay] AS 
    Datepart
    ("d"
     ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MyDayString] AS 
    '[Date].[Calendar].&[200603' + Cstr([Measures].[MyDay]) + ']' 
  MEMBER [Measures].[SomeOther] AS 
    (
      StrToMember
      (
        [Measures].[MyDayString]
       ,constrained
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[MyDay]
   ,[Measures].[SomeOther]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Tail
  (
    Descendants
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[8]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
    )
   ,10
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Above returns the following:

[image]

So something like this in your cube:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MyDay] AS 
    Datepart
    ("d"
     ,MyDateDimension.CurrentMember.Properties("MyProperty")
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MyDayString] AS 
    StrToMember('MyDateDimension.&[2015]&[4]&[' + Cstr([Measures].[MyDay]) + ']') 
  MEMBER [Measures].[SomeOther] AS 
    (
      StrToMember
      (
        [Measures].[MyDayString]
       ,constrained
      )
     ,[Measures].[Other]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[MyDay]
   ,[Measures].[SomeOther]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{MyDateDimension.MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM YourCube;
```

Comment: @aguyCalledGerald - was this any help at all?!

Comment: Hi, thank you, but can you also tell me why my version does not work?!

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald currently I'm unsure - I will try to further simplify the AdvWrks example and investigate further. I suspect it is connected with the order in which different parts of the query are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `SUM` function in the definition of `[Measures].[SomeOther]`. It will accept calculated members.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[SomeOther] as 
SUM(
   MyDateDimension.[MyMember], 
   [Measures].[Other]
   )
```

Comment: the dimension attribute was not found (it means "MyProperty"). problem with stored procedure DatePart.