# How to build a dynamic MDX formula for a calculated member?

Tags: dynamic, mdx

I am trying to create a Calculated Member to get a sum up to last week.
No problem to get the week value (I need it to be two digits i.e. '05', so adding 100-1 )

```
with
Member [Measures].Week as 
  'right(str(int(99+datepart ( ''ww'', Now()))),2)'
```

-- That works as expected

```
member [Measures].SalesUpToWeek as
  'strtomember(
     "aggregate(periodstodate([Dim].[2015],[Dim].[2015].[" + ([Measures].Week) + "]),[Measures].[Sales])")'
```

I get the literal value

```
aggregate(
    periodstodate([Dim].[2015],[Dim].[2015].[25])
   ,[Measures].[Sales]
)
```

What I need is the value of this `MDX` calculation.

All other attempts end up with a syntax error. Just as an example

```
member [Measures].SumToWeek as 
 'aggregate(
     periodstodate(
       [Dim].[2015],[Dim].[2015].[' + strtomember([Measures].Week) + '])
   ,[Measures].[Sales])'
```

Error

> Lexical error at line 2, column 0. Encountered:  after : "[\n"

Any idea?

Comment: I will shortly add `Edit2` to my answer as I think I now know what is going on: this is an interesting case.

Answer (score 0):

This is your error:

```
strtomember([Measures].Week)
```

Let us say that `[Measures].Week` is equal to 15 then you are trying to do this:

```
strtomember(15)
```

So there are two errors in the above:

1. You're feeding a numeric into a functions that converts Strings to Memebers
2. You need to feed in the full string representation of the member i.e."[Dim].[2015].[15]"

Maybe try putting the `strToMember` function around the string that is the representation of the member:

```
MEMBER[Measures].SumToWeek AS
 'aggregate(
     periodstodate(
       [Dim].[2015],
       strtomember('[Dim].[2015].[' + [Measures].Week + ']', constrained)
     )
   ,[Measures].[Sales])'
```

Here is the MSDN reference for the function `strtomember`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146022.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

---

**Edit**

Looking at this previous post: ([StrToMember does not accept calculated measure (mdx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629567/strtomember-does-not-accept-calculated-measure-mdx))
...you need to create the member before feeding it into the new measure, so:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Week] AS 
    Right
    (
      Str(Int(99 + Datepart('ww',Now())))
     ,2
    ) 
  MEMBER [Dim].[2015].[TargetWeek] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      '[Dim].[2015].[' + [Measures].Week + ']'
     ,constrained
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].SumToWeek AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      PeriodsToDate
      (
        [Dim].[2015]
       ,[Dim].[2015].[TargetWeek]
      )
     ,[Measures].[Sales]
    )
```

---

**Edit2**

Ok if you wish to use `PeriodsToDate` then we need to use `StrToSet` and then use the member in this set inside the function. This is because custom members lose their family ties and are therefore useless inside some `mdx` functions.
Here is a *working* script in `AdvWrks` illustrating the approach I'm suggesting:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Wk] AS 
    Right
    (
      Str(Int(99 + Datepart('ww',Now())))
     ,2
    ) 
  SET [TargetWeek] AS 
    StrToSet
    (
     '[Date].[Calendar Weeks].[Calendar Week].[Week ' + cstr([Measures].[Wk]) + ' CY 2007]'

    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[SumToWeek] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      PeriodsToDate
      (
        [Date].[Calendar Weeks].[Calendar Year]
       ,[TargetWeek].item(0).item(0)
      )
     ,([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[SumToWeek]} ON 0,
  [Product].[Product Categories].[All] ON 1  
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: I already tried both suggestions before posting :)

Whytheq: Syntax error

Sourav_Agasti: No function matches signature '<String> + <Member>'

Answer (score 0):

`[Measures].Week` is already a string entity. You don't need to put `StrToMember` around it. Instead you should have it outside the string you dynamically defined.

```
with
Member [Measures].Week as 
  "right(str(int(99+datepart ( ''ww'', Now()))),2)"

member [Measures].SumToWeek as 
aggregate(
            periodstodate(
                        [Dim].[2015],
                        StrToMember("[Dim].[2015].[" + [Measures].Week + "]")
                         )
            ,
            [Measures].[Sales]
         )
```

Comment: Hi Sourav - this will not work. I will add a full edit to my post later today - with explanation and working `AdvWrks` example.

Answer (score 0):

I got an interesting suggestion on Pentaho forums that pointed me to a nice blog post which allowed to write an elegant solution:

http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com.es/2009/10/current-date-function-on-mondrian.html

```
with
member [Measures].sm as aggregate(
    periodstodate(
        currentdatemember([Dim],'["Dim"]\.[yyyy]'),                     -- current year
        currentdatemember([Dim],'["Dim"]\.[yyyy]\.[ww]').lag(1)   -- previous week
    ),
    [Measures].[Sales])
```

Thks

Comment: very nice - shame `currentdatemember` is `mondrian` only.